# Is is possible to run a 16GB DIMM next to 4GB DIMM

Tags: memory, acer-aspire

Is is possible to run a 4GB DIMM with a 16GB DIMM on an Acer Aspire XC-780?  There are only 2 memory slots.

Answer (score 1):

[ACER Aspire XC-780](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/DT.B5EEK.003) supports up to 32GB DDR4 RAM.

> DDR4
>
> 8 GB (standard)
>
> Up to 32 GB (maximum)

The manufacturer makes no mention of limit per slot so 16GB DIMMs should be supported in a 2*16GB (=32GB) configuration. Any other DDR4 configuration is also possible, including 4GB+16GB. Crucial.com confirms it.

Comment: @fixer1234 *Any other DDR4 configuration is also possible* is about that. I also mentioned that Crucial.com confirms that several different DIMMs are compatible with this PC.

Answer (score 0):

The XC-780 specification limits only 32GB of max installable RAM.
Also the mainboard chipset limits 16GB/slot. The most important thing
is the memory form factor, of course, so it must be DDR4.

ANY memory module with max 16GB can be used regardless the another module
size, so 16 + 4 will work. I mean the PC will boot up, see all the 20GB
RAM, can use it, fully functional.

There's other things which won't work, like dual-channel requirements
not met (same memory size), BUT this is not mandatory, the answer for
the original question still YES, it will work.